# MS word table formatting is destroyed in no cause

Tags: microsoft-office-2007

I have several table in a word-2007 document.In those tables I aligned words by entering spaces manually(see the image). When I copy and paste those tables manually one by one into a new document then my original/source formatting is destroyed.
I am attaching before and after image for those tables.

**Before:**
[image: Before pasting]

**After:**
[image: After pasting]
I tried pasting options but failed

Look the words after equal sign is broken!!
I am facing another problem much related to it that when i works immediate below row of another row the THAT formatting of the above rows is automatically destroyed just like copy pasting problems.

Comment: Before and after column widths are not equal, so you see the result of word auto-wrapping. Align data with tabs or divide the cells.

Comment: It would be easier to use a right align tab in your table paragraph format :)

Comment: @ Akina why so happens I did not reformat anything just copy-pasted? moverover there may have a chance that attached imgages are different in size!!

Comment: @ DavidPostill could you be a bit more clear? how to do this? is that problem is just for 2007?

Comment: *I did not reformat anything just copy-pasted?* You have copypasted the whole table? It's possible that new document (default) styles were applied to the pasted content, and some paragraph/table parameters were altered.